# jQuery arrange li order by clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

Need to change li position by clicking to move up or to move down.

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Item1  <a class="moveUp">Move Up</a> <a class="moveDown">Move Down</a></li>
    <li>Item2  <a class="moveUp">Move Up</a> <a class="moveDown">Move Down</a></li>
    <li>Item3  <a class="moveUp">Move Up</a> <a class="moveDown">Move Down</a></li>
    <li>Item4  <a class="moveUp">Move Up</a> <a class="moveDown">Move Down</a></li>
    <li>Item5  <a class="moveUp">Move Up</a> <a class="moveDown">Move Down</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So what should happen here, for example, if we click Move up on Item2, the Item 2 will move up before Item 1.

I tryed to do like this, but it doesn't work:

```
$(".moveUp").click(function () {
    var thisLine = $(this).parent();
    var prevLine = thisLine.prev();
    prevLine.insertAfter(thisLine);
});
```

Hope some one can help me...

Comment: If there is an answer that has worked for you, please mark it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work and will also not move the element outside of the UL when you try and move it up at the top or down at the bottom:

```
$('.moveUp').click(function(){
    var liItem = $(this).parent();
    if (liItem.prev().is('li'))
    {
        liItem.insertBefore(liItem.prev())
    }
});

$('.moveDown').click(function(){
    var liItem = $(this).parent();
    if (liItem.next().is('li'))
    {
        liItem.insertAfter(liItem.next())
    }
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BDecp/

Also, your code should be wrapped with this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Code Here
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$(".moveUp").click(function () {
    var thisLine = $(this).parent();
    var prevLine = thisLine.prev();
    prevLine.before(thisLine);
});

$(".moveDown").click(function () {
    var thisLine = $(this).parent();
    var prevLine = thisLine.next();
    prevLine.after(thisLine);
});
```

Working jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qGFfU/).

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
$(".moveUp").click(function () {
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    $parent.prev().before($parent);
});
$(".moveDown").click(function () {
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    $parent.next().after($parent);
});
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/vQmHU/

Answer (score 1):

this one only rearranges the list items:

```
$(".moveUp").click(function () {
  var $parent = $(this).parent().closest("li");
  $parent.prev().before($parent);
});

$(".moveDown").click(function () {
  var $parent = $(this).parent().closest("li");
  $parent.next().after($parent);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/j7xtS/2/

```
$('ul').on('click', 'a', function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        $li = $this.parent();

    if ($this.hasClass('moveUp') &&  $li.prev().length>0){
        $li.prev().before($li[0]);
    }
    else if ($this.hasClass('moveDown') && $li.next().length>0){
        $li.next().after($li[0]);
    }
});​
```