# Using jQuery to Rotate the order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html like this:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li class="item">a</li>
  <li class="item">b</li>
  <li class="item">c</li>
</ul>
```

What I'd like to accomplish using jQuery is to have the order rotated.  So after one call the resulting html would be:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li class="item">c</li>
  <li class="item">a</li>
  <li class="item">b</li>
</ul>
```

And after another ...

```
<ul id="list">
  <li class="item">b</li>
  <li class="item">c</li>
  <li class="item">a</li>
</ul>
```

And so on.  What is the proper way to accomplish this?

Comment: Give it a go and come back to us when (and if) you have issue with what you are trying :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014752/jquery-arrange-li-order-by-clicking-on-a-link

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555415/how-to-randomly-sort-list-items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the last item and prepend it.

```
$('#list li').last().prependTo('#list');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9fja5t35/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Pop the last item off the list and prepend it to the list like this:

```
var $list = $('#list');
$list.find('.item:last').prependTo($list);
```

This is a case of [micro-optimization](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/), but as long as we have to create 2 jquery objects (and there's no easy way around that), declaring the list first, then using it to limit the scope of the search for the item with `find` should be faster than using 2 selectors with the document as the search scope.

Comment: You don't have to remove it to make it work: 
    $("#list li:last-child").prependTo("#list");

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#list li:last").insertBefore("#list li:first")
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/253g0ow0/)